# Misunderstanding with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I would like to parse the Pcap-file. My code is very simple

```
filename="example-01.pcap"
myreader = PcapReader(filename)
PK=myreader.read_packet()
```

Then, I look in PK, and receive

```
PK[0].summary()
Out[5]: 'Raw'

PK[0].show()
###[ Raw ]### 
load      =
```

> \x0c\x9d\x92\xb45t\x00\xdb\xdf\xc7pm\x08\x00E\x00\x00b\xe0y@\x00@\x06D\xae\xc0\xa8\x01\x89\xac\xd9\xa6c\xdbt\x01\xbbM\xe7n\x89d\x9f\x05\x8f\x80\x18\x05\xd0\x14\xe0\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\nD<\xbb\x12z\x14\x0e\x95\x17\x03\x03\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\xf4t\xb0\xcc\xb7\x109\xfbG\xee2\xca\xed\x9d\xd9\xc7\xb0\xb6!\xed\xdc\xc9\xe7\xdcq*\xd7\x0e\xab2\xd4Bg

But what I am expecting is something like this:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= ….
  src= ….
  type= ….
###[ IP ]###
     …….
###[ ICMP ]###
 ….
###[ Raw ]###
```

and

```
'Ether / IP / ICMP 172.16.20.10 > 4.2.2.1 echo-request 0 / Raw'
```

I understand, that I misunderstand something in Scapy’ logic, but I can’t catch, where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PK[0]` does not make sense. `PK` is a packet, you should be using calls such as `PK[Raw]` or `PK[Ether]`. In your case, a simple `PK.show()` would probably get you what you want

Comment: Sorry, but PK.show() or PK.summary() get the same results. And PK[Raw].show() -  or PK[Ether]... get a mistake:  "NameError: name 'Raw' is not defined" :-(

Comment: When I stick your raw bytes into a byte string, and call `Ether(raw_bytes)`, I get back a valid-looking Ethernet/IP/TCP packet header. If OTOH I call `Packet(raw_bytes)`, I get something similar to what you're showing. I would examine the header of your pcap file (with wireshark's `capinfos` utility perhaps). I'm wondering if it doesn't have the correct encapsulation marked, so that scapy doesn't know to decode it as an Ethernet packet.